# If you knock a creature back 10 feet using Thunderbolt Strike, and a wall is 5 feet behind the creature, what happens?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, cleric, forced-movement

I envision the Thunderbolt Strike as throwing the target creature away from it, not gently pushing it away. I mean lightning is an instantaneous thing, and 10 feet is more than just losing your balance.

If the target of a Thunderbolt Strike is 5 feet from a wall when the target gets knocked back 10 feet toward it, what happens?

- Will the target just stop when they reach the wall?
- Will they take damage as they still have 5 feet more to move when they hit it?
- Or might they bounce back in my direction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thunderstrike says (PHB p.62)

> At 6th level, when you deal lightning damage to a Large or smaller creature, you can also push it up to 10 feet away from you.

Well, if there is a wall in the way, you can't push them 10' away from you.

> I envision the Thunderbolt Strike as throwing the target creature away from it, not gently pushing it away. I mean lightning is an instantaneous thing and 10' is more than just losing your balance.

Well, no. The creature is "push[ed]", it doesn't even knock them prone. You can envision what you like but RAW, the creature is staggering away from you - running into a wall is going to help more than it hinders.

Comment: It could throw them away violently... just everybody lands on their feet for some reason.

Comment: The word "push" implies a particular thing, like being push around by a strong wind -- you stay upright and just forced back away from the source in a straight line.  Similar language is used in the Warlock Eldritch Invocation Repelling blast, "When you hit a creature with eldritch blast. you can push the creature up to 10 feet away from you in a straight line."