# Does Eldritch Blast’s Repelling Blast invocation push a creature downward into the ground?

Tags: dnd-5e, cantrips, eldritch-invocations, 3d-space

If I am above a creature and cast *eldritch blast* with the Repelling Blast invocation, does it get hit into the ground?

Comment: I assume this is about the D&D warlock, but *eldritch blast* has been the signature ability of the warlock class for nearly 20 years, across three different rulesets. Pretty sure all of them had a “repelling blast,” too, though I guess in 4e it wouldn’t have been called an “invocation” probably. Anyway, point is, in order to determine the rules for you, we need to know what rules you’re playing under: D&D, probably, but 3.5e, 4e, or 5e? (The latest ruleset is 5e, so this is likely what you’re playing if you’re unsure.)

Comment: I am playing 5e and yes i am speaking about the Warlock

Comment: What do you mean "[hit] into the ground?". Like literally the creature is now "in the ground", or do you mean it "collides with the ground"?

Comment: I thought it would be "in the ground" because it would go 10 feet away from me so i'm asking would they go inside the ground or just slam into it

Comment: This previous answer of mine about walls also applies equally well to solid ground: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/194921/40516

Comment: Related: [What are the effects of a Warlock's Repelling Blast when pushing the target?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/79460/23547), [If you knock a creature back 10' using Thunderbolt Strike and a wall is 5' behind him what happens?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/70104/23547)

Answer (score 10):

### They don't go into the ground

The feature says: "you can push the creature up to 10 feet away from you in a straight line". Since that straight line goes into the ground, and it doesn't mention what happens during collisions. We are left to conclude: Nothing happens.

The alternative, that the creature is now buried underground is unreasonable, since it equates to death. If the creature isn't buried, but instead stuck in a hole, remember that the invocation can be applied multiple times, possibly leaving it in a 10-40ft deep hole. So even if it doesn't outright kill the creature, at least it is out of the fight, and can be picked off easily later. So from a balance perspective this is way too strong for an invocation.

However, talk to your DM. At least they might allow you to push the creature in the "most straight line" possible, thus still allowing you to use your invocation. Or perhaps house rule some consequence for colliding with the ground or other obstacle.

Since we are now entering opinion territory, I'd advice against making the effect too powerful. Forced movement can already be very strong in the right circumstances, as anyone who has pushed a creature into a chasm can attest. Maybe a DEX save to avoid going prone, or an extra 1d4 damage.